# How to avoid hardcoding of ouput link value in VF email template?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-template

I am designing a Visualforce email template for an approval process and trying to provide a link to Salesforce for the approver. I want to avoid hardcoding of the URL to avoid a post deployment step :)

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://cs21.salesforce.com/{!relatedto.Id}">Link</apex:outputLink>
```

The following tag doesn't compile and shows up

> Syntax error. Missing '}'

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm() + '/' +{!relatedto.Id}">Link</apex:outputLink>
```

The following tag compiles successfully but returns a broken link

```
<apex:outputLink value="!URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm() + '/' +{!relatedto.Id}"></apex:outputLink>
```

http://%21url.getsalesforcebaseurl%28%29.toexternalform%28%29+++%27/'

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm()` We can use this in Apex class..

But in VF page we need to use `$CurrentPage.URL` this will return complete url of current page..

Example
`https://ratan.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/contactcloudPage`

SO just remove the `/apex/contactcloudPage` from url using `LEFT`

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))+relatedto.Id}">Link</apex:outputLink>
```

`FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))`

**9 means number of the character from which to start searching from left to right.**

`FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))` checks for the first `/` after 9 character from left to right.. that return the first `/` position number. So If My url is `https://ratan.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/contactcloudPage` then it will check for first `/` after `https:// means It will pick the force.com/` this `/` and return the position no and `LEFT` will use this position number for substring

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&siteLang=en_US

Comment: I think you can even remove '/' because it cause double // in generated template

Comment: @kurunve check my updated ans

Comment: Second one is not working if you send email. as well as third one

Comment: @kurunve Thanks.. I am not tested with email template..

Comment: @Bennie 9 means number of the character from which to start searching from left to right.  https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&siteLang=en_US

Comment: @Ratan I understand what the FIND function does but why 9? I tried creating a formula field with `$CurrentPage.URL` but it's not available.

Comment: @Bennie `FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))` checks for the first `/` after 9 character from left to right.. that return the first `/`  position number. So If My url is `https://ratan.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/contactcloudPage` then it will check for first `/` after `https://` means It will pick the `force.com/` this `/` and return the position no and LEFT will use this position number for  substring