# using custom link to VF page in an email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, workflow, email-template

I have an HTML email template (**NOT** a VF template) that should be sent by a workflow rule when the record status is changed to *Converted*.

rather than a link to the record in SalesForce, I want a link on the email template to point to the record shown in my VF Page, so the link would be something like

```
https://domain.salesforce.com/apex/SystemChangeRequest?id=a3Qg0000000HaEdEAK&mode=view
```

I looked at [Bob Buzzard's answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8837/detail-page-link-under-email-template) and tried adding:

```
Click {HYPERLINK(Left($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190,(find('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190))) + Request_for_System_Change__c.Id, 'Request' )}
```

I also put a special *URL* field in my custom object, which can be populated by the trigger on save. This new field is called *link_to_request_)c* and is populated in the *Save* event of my trigger as below:

```
String sUrlRewrite = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();

system.debug('sUrlRewrite  = ' + sUrlRewrite);
//  Example: c.cs7.visual.force.com
// https://cs87.salesforce.com/apex/SystemChangeRequest?id=a3K8E0000000CMyUAM&mode=view
sUrlRewrite = 'https://'
    + sUrlRewrite.substring(0,5) 
    + 'salesforce.com'
    + '/apex/SystemChangeRequest?mode=view&id='
    + sId;

r.link_to_request__c= sUrlRewrite;
```

so in my email template I tried adding that as well, but when I click on the *add link* button in editing HTML template, it just shows me the **add HTML link** dialog:

[image]

and when the email is sent, it looks like this:

[image]

I am stuck with this, I could of course hard-code the domain name in each domain, but I'd rather try and have it done dynamically if possible.

**UPDATE following answer by bennie**

so I have a formula field in my custom object called `UrlFormulaField` using the formula 
`LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_360, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_360)) & '/apex/systemchangerequest?id=' & Id & '&mode=view'` and this creates the correct URL as

```
https://domain.salesforce.com//apex/systemchangerequest?id=a3Qg0000000HaMImode=view
```

so in my HTML template I want to add this as a Merge field link, but when I click add the Merge field, select it, click the *add link* button and paste in the merge field it doesn't add it as a link:

[image]

so what is the correct way to add the merge field as a link?

Comment: try this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-to-avoid-hardcoding-of-ouput-link-value-in-vf-email-template/105189#105189

Comment: @Ratan: Thanks but this is an assignment template used in a workflow with merge fields - how can I use this method to get my VF page with record Id as a link in my SF communication template?

Comment: Have you created a Formula field with this `{HYPERLINK(Left($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190,(find('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190))) + Request_for_System_Change__c.Id, 'Request' )}` and use this formula field in  email template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a formula field `Instance_URL__c` on your object -

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_360, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_360))
```

Now in your template use it as a merge field. I have taken Account object as an example.

```
{!Account.Instance_URL__c}{!Account.Id}
```

In your instance something like

```
Click {!Request_for_System_Change__c.UrlFormulaField__c}{!Request_for_System_Change__c.Id} to go to change request
```

Click on link and insert the formula string like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and this looks good, but I am having trouble inserting it as a clickable link in my HTML Template. I am editing the *HTML Template* in SalesForce, and when I click on the **add link** button I get the script prompt as above in my question, but SF doesn't put a link in my email template when I click OK

Comment: @OurManInBananas This above will create a simple text.. You need to wrapp this text inside `HYPERLINK` function.

Comment: @Bennie: so it would be something like `Click {HYPERLINK(!Request_for_System_Change__c.UrlFormulaField__c)}` ?

Comment: @Bennie: Thanks for all your help and patience Bennie. I tried selecting the text and clicking the *link* button then adding it as `http://{!Request_for_System_Change__c.UrlFormulaField__c}{!Request_for_System_Change__c.Id}` but it still won't go as a link in the HTML template - please see the update to my question

Comment: @OurManInBananas You are doing it wrong! Remove the default string `http://` which appears on the 'Please enter URL' window. Just put `{!Request_for_System_Change__c.UrlFormulaField__c}{!Request_for_System_Change__c.Id}` as I suggested in my post and then put your text around it.

Comment: @Bennie: strange thing is, even when clear the `http://` nothing is added into the template.

Comment: @OurManInBananas As per your screenshot you are entering `{!Request_for_System_Change__c.UrlFormulaField__c}` whereas you have to put `{!Request_for_System_Change__c.UrlFormulaField__c}{!Request_for_System_Change__c.I‌​d}` for a proper URL to be constructed. Also make sure that you have created the formula field correctly.

Comment: @Bennie, LOL, funny story, Internet Explorer strikes again, I waste 2 hours faffing around with this, almost shouting at my workstation, SalesForce, StackExchange... my colleague tried it on FireFox and guess what :)

Comment: @Bennie, thanks ever so much for your help, my problem is solved!

Comment: @OurManInBananas glad it helped