# How to get the server name dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-vf-component, dynamic-visualforce

I'm using below line of code in the vf component,this is a part of repeat tag.

```
<td class="center"><a href="https://cs14.salesforce.com/{!o.id}/e?retURL=%2F{!o.id}">Edit</a></td>
```

This is working fine,but when we move to other sandbox or production then i have to replace the `https://cs14` with corresponding server name.

Is there any way to fetch the values dynamically instead of changing manually.
Something like  "`URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()`".with in the above tag?

Comment: why don't you use VF global variable Action.. You can directly redirect to edit page..

Comment: you are fetching value in Apex or in VF?

Comment: @user7447  try something like `/apex/vfpage?id=recordId` or `/recordId` in VF page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Global variable Action. Salesforce will generate URL for you. You don't have to do Anything.. This button will redirect to Account Edit page..

You just need to pass record Id

```
<apex:commandButton value="EDIT" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit, Account.Id)}" />
```

[**Refer this documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm)

---

**Another option you could use this**

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))+relatedto.Id+'/e?retURL=%2F'+o.Id}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
```

**[Refer this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-to-avoid-hardcoding-of-ouput-link-value-in-vf-email-template)**

Comment: That works only with button.In our case its an hyperlink for the Account  Name and Action.  Currently i'm using the url class in the backend and fetching the value onto vf template.Besides that is there any other options.

Comment: that doesn't work in my case.txs

Comment: relatedto.Id will work in case of navigating to the record page - its clear and fine. In this case i 'm using <td class="center"><a href="{!o.fullFileURL}/{!o.id}/e?retURL=%2F{!o.id}">Edit</a></td> which will navigate to the edit page and after savin returns to the record page.   where fullFileURL holds the base url.

Comment: @user7447 this is just an example.. after `+relatedto.Id` yoiu can add `/e` `+relatedto.Id+'/e'` so this redirect to edit page..

Comment: Can we append the retURL=%2F{!o.id}  after '/e' ?

Comment: @user7447 yes you can.. Just like this `+relatedto.Id+'/e?retURL=%2F'+o.Id`